# The code does not enter the right if statement

Tags: java

The code below executes properly in debug mode, but when I run it I encounter the following issue with the if statement:

Even when `t == 0`, it enters the else block instead of entering the `if` block. I also tried to remove `else` and write `if (t > 0)` but that didn't work.

```
for (t = 0; t < T; t++) {
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            if (t == 0) {
                // Lines of code..... 
            } else {
                // Lines of code....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what data type is `t`?

Comment: What's the type of your variables?

Comment: Your code is correct. It works perfectly for integer variable t,i,j. Moreover, your if block will be executed 36 times.

Comment: Thanks everyone. @penne12 suggested a way and it works for now.

Comment: You are welcome, click the check mark next to the answer to help everyone know that my answer helped you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (t < 1) {
    // Lines of codes..... 
} else {
    // Lines of codes....
}
```

That will trigger when the `t` is less then 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked for now, I hope it does not give me error again.

Comment: You are welcome, click the check mark next to the answer to help everyone know that my answer helped you :)

Comment: I am sorry for asking this silly question but I am new to stackflow. I cant find the check mark.

Comment: @user3469181, you did it! Thanks

Comment: @penne12...I have also shared another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29369265/arrayindexoutofboundsexception-i-get-this-strange-error-even-when-i-loop-the-a

Comment: sorry that one got posted half way...i have shared that question, if you happen to have the time, could please take a look. Many thanks..!!!

Answer (score -2):

From what you have written, I am assuming that you that you to print the first output when t is a certain value.  If you change the if statement to (t<1) the second output should execute.

```
public class StackOverflow 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int t, j, i;
    int T = 6;

    for (t = 0; t < T; t++) 
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) 
            {
                if (t < 0) 
                {
                    // Lines of codes.....
                    System.out.println("Output 1");
                } 
                else 
                {
                    // Lines of codes....
                    System.out.println("Output 2");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```