# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, I get this strange error, even when I loop the array keeping in mind the index

Tags: java, eclipse, multidimensional-array

I know that arrays start with index zero and, when I call an array, I need to keep this in mind.

For example:

```
public int name [] = name [3]
for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
    name [i] = 0 ;
}
```

And I proceed in the same way when I write the code for my model. However, I get the error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` repeatedly.

Here is my code:

```
public int T = 10;
public int A = 100;
public int t = 0;
public int a = 0
public double d  = 2.5;
public double weight = 0;
public double vision; // I initialize this later and it goes smoothly.
public double mem_payoff_time_action[][] = new double [T][A]; 
public double reward_problem[][] = new double [T][A];
public int action_taken[][] = new int [T][A];
public double action_mean []= new double [A]; 


public double getaction_mean() { 
    for ( int p = 0; p < action_mean.length ;p++){
        action_mean[p] = (p + 1);   
    }
    return action_mean[a];
}

public double calculate_mem_payoff_matrix_initialize (){
    for ( int t: Time ){
        for (a = 0 ; a == (action_mean.length - 1) ; a++){
            mem_payoff_time_action[t][a] = 0;
        }
    }
    return mem_payoff_time_action[t][a];
}

public double attach_this_weight(){
    for (a = 0 ; a < A ;a++){
        if (action_taken[t][a] == 1){
            if (vision == 1){
                if (mem_payoff_time_action[t][a] > 0.0 ){
                    weight = 0.1 ;
                }
                else{
                    weight = - (0.1); 
                }
            } 
            if (vision == 2){
                if (mem_payoff_time_action[t][a] > 0.0 ){
                    weight = 0.2 ;
                }
                else{
                    weight   = - (0.2); 
                }
            }
            if (vision == 3){
                if (mem_payoff_time_action[t][a] > 0.0 ){
                    weight = 0.3 ;
                }
                else{
                    weight   = - (0.3); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return weight;
}

public double calculate_reward_cummulative(){
    int p= 0;
    if (t ==0){
        for ( a= 0 ; a < action_mean.length ; a++){
            if (a == first_action_index){
                if (mem_payoff_time_action[0][a] < 0){
                    reward_problem[0][a] = d + (weight* mem_payoff_time_action[0][a]); 
                    else{
                        reward_problem[0][a] = d + (weight* mem_payoff_time_action[0][a]);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    reward_problem[0][p] = d;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            for( p =0; p < action_mean.length  ;p++){
                if(action_taken[t][p]== 1){
                    if(mem_payoff_time_action[t][p] < 0){
                        reward_problem[t][p] = (reward_problem[t-1][p]) + (weight* mem_payoff_time_action[t][p]) ; 
                    }
                    else{
                        reward_problem[t][p] = (reward_problem[t-1][p]) + (weight* mem_payoff_time_action[t][p]) ;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    reward_problem[t][p] = reward_problem[t-1][p]; 
                }
            }
        }
        return reward_problem[t][a];
    }
```

I get the error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for the `reward_problem[][]` array in the method `calculate_reward_cummulative`

And, I keep getting this error for most of my code.

I was receiving the same error for`mem_payoff_time_action[][]`. I was writing:

```
for (t = 0; t< T; t++){
    for (a = 0; a < A ; a++){
        mem_payoff_time_action[t][a] = 0;
    }
}
```

In order to fix the error, I change 'A' with `action_mean.length`. And,  I created an array called Time.

```
public int Time [] = new int [T];
public int calcualte_time (){
    for (int t : Time){
        Time [t] = 0;
    }
    return Time [t];
}
```

And, I rewrote the code as mentioned below. And, everything was fine. However, I still don't understand why I get this error.

Comment: Some ident will be nice.

Comment: Also please don't use capital letters as variable names...

Comment: I didnt understand what you suggested or are asking for..

Comment: @user3469181, can you post the exact error you get? and the exact line of code where you get it?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100
 at fame.User.calculate_reward_cummulative(User.java:617)
 at fame.User.main(User.java:1403)

Comment: What I posted a while ago is the exact error I got...as above I have not copied my entire code...lines are not the same...I get the error at "return reward_problem[t][a]" when I call the method calculate_cummulative_reward". If you want me to post my codes for the main as well, do let me know. Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

as you rightly pointed out the error you are getting is in calculate_reward_cummulative method, the reason being the following:

return reward_problem[t][a];

the array will logically have 10 rows (index 0-9) and 100 columns (index 0-99). if you try to get the value for the 100th index, you are bound to get this exception.

here t is coming as 0 but as a is a global variable and you are using it as a counter in the for loop,

for ( a= 0 ; a < action_mean.length ; a++)

when the loop ends the value of the counter ie "a" is 100, thus you are trying to return reward_problem[0][100], thus jvm is throwing exception.

please try to use a different counter variable and return the appropriate array index.

Comment: I did what you propose and I still get the same error.